# RTP stream with bareSIP

Tags: rtsp, rtp, baresip

my current setup involves streaming from a GoPro to a linux box, and I managed to get bareSIP running on the box to stream the video locally with the 'v' command. However, there's no documentation or commands to configure an RTP broadcasting stream. Would anyone have any insight into publishing an RTP/RTSP output stream for other users to view on their devices?

Answer (score 0):

I've used Unreal Streaming Media components and found them to be very good.  They are lightweight and fast yet very powerful.
Using Unreal components you could install the stream forwarder on your laptop, point it at the RTSP stream and tell it to forward to the Distribution server application.
This app can host thousands of connections (supposedly) and last I looked you didn't need a license if you have 3 or fewer sources.  The stream can be viewd via their own small player app, via a web player such as jPlayer or via VLC etc.

I've been pretty happy with this before - it saved me from having to use the Live555 streaming mess.
Good Luck!